# Firebug: Find outer width of elements

Tags: firebug

When you inspect an element, it can show you the width inside the padding, but not the whole width (padding + content). Is there a way to display the full width somehow? (similar to Chrome inspector)

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug you have several places were you can get the total width of an element.

1. **Through the [*Layout* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Layout_Side_Panel)**

   There you need to calculate the total width, though.

   [image: Total element width within the *Layout* side panel]
2. **Through the [Quick Info Box](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_Info_Box)**

   The Quick Info Box can be enabled through the [*HTML* panel option *Show Quick Info Box*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Options_Menu). It will then be displayed whenever you hover an HTML element within the *HTML* panel or in other places throughout Firebug. The total element width is listed there under the point *offsetWidth*.

   [image: Total element width within the Quick Info Box]
3. **Through the rulers within the page**

   Not very accurate, though for roughly sighting you can use the rulers shown for an element when you hover the layout box within the *Layout* side panel having the [option *Show Rulers and Guides*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Layout_Side_Panel#Options_Menu) enabled.

   [image: Total Element width via rulers within the page]
4. **Through the [*DOM* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#DOM)**

   The total width of the element is listed there as *offsetWidth*.

   [image: Total element width within the *DOM* side panel]
5. **Through the [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel)**

   The total element width is available through the `offsetWidth` DOM property. To get it, you need to access the element first. E.g. the last inspected element is available through `$0`, so you can execute this within the [command line](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line) to get the total width:

   `$0.offsetWidth`

   [image: Total element width within the *Console* panel]